# How can I add data to a DB? PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to not be inserting data into fields properly. The fields and tables all exists and I'm positive that I'm connecting to the database correctly. The fields all remain empty :(

```
  $query = ("INSERT INTO 'users' (phone) VALUES ('$phone') WHERE username='$userid'");
  mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: if that is the exact query you are sending try to replace the single quotes around the table name with  a ` like so: `\`users\``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **update** query :

```
  $query="UPDATE users
    SET phone='$phone'
    WHERE username='$userid'";
```

Comment: +1 It definitely looks like the OP is mistaking an INSERT for an UPDATE.

Answer (score 4):

INSERT doesn't have a WHERE in it's syntax:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be using update....

```
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

mysql_query("UPDATE Persons SET Age = '36'
WHERE FirstName = 'Peter' AND LastName = 'Griffin'");

mysql_close($con);
```